# Run CakePHP tests in Zend Studio

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, zend-studio, cakephp-2.3

I'm able to run my CakePHP unit tests from the console, but it would be a lot easier if I could use the built in features of Zend Studio 9 to run those tests.

I've not been able to find any tips on how to run CakePHP tests in Zend Studio.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried loading my tests that work in a web browser and they do not work in Zend Studio. Know that if you plan on running your tests in Zend Studio, chances are they will have to be written specifically to work in Zend Studio and will likely break from working in the browser.

Comment: Yea, this was my fear. Bootstrapping CakePHP to run the native PHPUnit tests looks like it would be difficult.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not so bad to use the web UI. I like the idea of maybe using Zend Studio to create quick tests that can then be used in the PHPUnit tests in cake. But I see them more as test driven development starting points for the developer than as a solution for QA.

Comment: I don't like the web UI because I can't checkmark what tests I want to run. I'm prefer to run tests as part of a build script.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that. That sounds like a great feature request for CakePHP! It would definitely make the test suite more robust.